# Outlook Add-In Event "When a mail is opened"

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

i want to display a message to the user (as an infobar for example) as soon as the user opens the mail. In the 'supported events' list i could not find an appropiate eventlistener that fires when a mail is opened. Does this event even exist? If yes, what is the name? If no, how else could i possibly achieve this task? It is a priority that i display an infobar and not set a category or any workaround like that.

Thanks in advance

I tried finding an appropiate eventlistener but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook activates some types of add-ins if the message or appointment that the user is reading or composing satisfies the activation rules of the add-in. The user can then choose the add-in from the Outlook UI to start it for the current item.

To have Outlook activate an add-in for specific conditions, specify activation rules in the add-in manifest by using the `Rule` elements. Read more about possible rules and workflows in the [Activation rules for contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/activation-rules) article.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: So the user must still manually start the add-in? I want the add-in to always automatically run as soon as the message is opened. Without any further user interaction other than initially opening his message for reading purposes.

Comment: Yes, this functionality does not currently exist. Please refer to Eugene's post to create or vote for new features on the Tech Community.